# case-preserving linux usernames and hostnames

Tags: linux, pam, shadow, case-sensitivity

Is there a way to set `pam` library to do case-preserving username validation? Is there a way to set `useradd` command to accept and preserve the case of usernames? I know usernames and URLs are not OS related, so better Linux preserve their case. Will `shadow` or `pam` accept if someone contributes case preserving module? I don't want to use samba active directory configuration.

**case-preserving**: `echo $USER` should print case preserved username, while `login` can ignore the case.

Comment: case-preserving

Comment: _case-preserving_ only makes sense in the context of case-insensitive matching. Otherwise, it's just case-sensitive. The "files" NSS backends are case sensitive. Some backends like ldap may not be depending on which attribute you use as  the username and how it's defined in the schema.

Comment: `echo $USER` should print case preserved username, while `login` can ignore the case.